# How to pick a type from union type with a variable

Tags: typescript

I have a type like this

```
type CreateOrUpdateMutationResult = { createArticle: boolean } | { updateArticle: boolean }
```

a param `result` is the type `CreateOrUpdateMutationResult`

I have a extra variable `isCreate` which can judge the result type

But how can I let typescript knows the result real type?

```
// here ts don't know the result type
const status = isCreate ? result.createArticle : result.updateArticle
```

I expect ts know the type of result

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `as` conversion to make it the right type if you know what it is.

```
interface CreateMutationResult { createArticle: boolean }
interface UpdateMutationResult { updateArticle: boolean }
type CreateOrUpdateMutationResult = CreateMutationResult | UpdateMutationResult
```

then

```
const status = isCreate ? (result as CreateMutationResult).createArticle : (result as UpdateMutationResult).updateArticle
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible solutions for this:

You can test for a unique key,

```
const status = 'createArticle' in result ? result.createArticle : result.updateArticle;
```

When you test for a key present in only one type, typescript is able to infer the type based on it.

Or you can use a typeguard,

```
function isCreateResult(result: CreateOrUpdateMutationResult, isCreate: boolean): result is { createArticle: boolean } {
    return isCreate; // or 'createArticle' in result
}

const status =  isCreateResult(result, isCreate) ? result.createArticle : result.updateArticle
```

as you can see the `isCreate` flag is not really needed as javascript allows for testing of keys in an idiomatic way.